# How to set Sigma value in CompactClassificationSVM in Matlab

Tags: matlab, svm

I'm new to Matlab and I would like to set the value of [Sigma](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/compactclassificationsvm-class.html#prop_Sigma) for the class [CompactClassificationSVM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/compactclassificationsvm-class.html)

I couldn't find away to set it's value. I tried for example;

```
CompactSVMModel.Sigma
```

But I got the error message:

```
Error using subsref
No appropriate method, property, or field 'Sigma' for class 'ClassificationECOC'.
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first train a support vector machine classifier using fitcsvm, with standardization of predictors set to  true, as input to your CompactClassificationSVM.

The syntax is

> mySVMModel = fitcsvm(X,Y,'Standardize',true)

where X is your vector of predictors, and Y your vector of class labels.

Standardization is  set to  false by default. You have to turn it on explicitly.

Then you can call

> CompactSVMModel = compact(mySVMModel)

and it will have Sigma set to what you trained it to be in the first step.

I don't know of any way to set the input Sigma at the training stage directly but you can set the prior probabilities of your classes, or weights on the input data respectively using the 'Prior' or 'Weights' keywords. See the Matlab documentation for fitclsvm for specific syntax of the options - it really depends on your specific application what to do.

Comment: Thank you ... But is there is way I could manually set the value for Sigma?

Comment: See edit. I don't think there is a way to do that directly since the Matlab SVM   computes your data mean and sigma to do the standardization, but you could possibly influence it indirectly  using prior probabilities or weights.